# Prove discontinuity of a 1-1 function mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I was wondering what the best approach would be to demonstrate the discontinuity of a one-to-one function $g$ defined such that it maps  $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ where $f(\mathbb{R}$) has a range of $[p,q)$.

Is my best bet to approach this topologically and show the inverse image $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The right way will very much depends on the function itself, but looking at $f^{-1}(\Bbb{R})$ is the wrong way, since $f^{-1}(\Bbb{R})$ is always $\Bbb{R}$ for every function $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, even discontinuous ones.

Comment: In this case, I would try looking at the point $a \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(a) = p$. Then apply the intermediate value theorem to $[a - 1, a]$ and $[a, a + 1]$ to contradict $f$ being one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.